# Chaining API requests with Axios in Node.js in a loop - doesn't work in order

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, axios

EDITED:
Tried below suggestions as well as something more, and now this is the code, I pretty much just made it all async await instead of then and catch...

```
makeNextAccount();
  

  console.log("Making :" + merchantsToCreate.length + " Accounts")

async function makeNextAccount(currentIndex) {
    for (const item of merchantsToCreate) {

try{
    let accId = "";
    
    var createAccBody = JSON.stringify(
        {
        "email":emails[item],
        "firstName":"sdd",
        "lastName":"dgdg"
    });
    
    
    var createAcc = {
      method: 'post',
      url: url1,
      headers: awsHeaders,
      data : createAccBody
    };

    const createdAccResult = await axios(createAcc); // wait for the request to finish

    await Promise.all(createdAccResult);
    console.log('Done!');

    accId = createdAccResult.data.accountId;
    console.log(JSON.stringify("ACCOUNT CREATED:" + accId));
} catch(err) {
    console.log("ERROR Create acc:" + err );
  }

  try{
    var initUnAuthBody = JSON.stringify(
        {
            "accountId": accId
        });
    
    var initUnAuth = {
      method: 'post',
      url: url2,
      headers: awsHeaders,
      data : initUnAuthBody
    };
    
    const initUnAuthResult = await axios(initUnAuth); // wait for the request to finish
    console.log(JSON.stringify("Init unAuth for:" +accId+", with response:" + initUnAuthResult.status));

  }catch(err) {
    console.log("ERROR unautinit:" + err);
  }

  try{
    var provisionBody = JSON.stringify(
        {
            "name":  accId,
            "active": "1"

        });
    
    var provision = {
      method: 'post',
      url: url3,
      headers: awsHeaders,
      data : provisionBody
    };

    const provisionResult = await axios(provision); // wait for the request to finish
    console.log(JSON.stringify("Provision for:" + accId+", with response:" +  provisionResult.status));

}catch(err) {
    console.log("ERROR provision:" + err);
  }

  try{
    var salesForceRecordody = JSON.stringify(
        {
            "email": emails[item],
            "accountId":  accId,

        });
    
    var salesForceRecord = {
      method: 'post',
      url: url4,
      headers: awsHeaders,
      data : salesForceRecordody
    };

    const salesForceRecordResult = await axios(salesForceRecord); // wait for the request to finish

    console.log(JSON.stringify("SalesForce Record for:" +accId+", with response:" + salesForceRecordResult.status));

    accCreatedList.push(accId); // Push to created list only when all steps are done
}catch(err) {
    console.log("ERROR Salesforce:" + err);
  }

    }
 }
```

And the result of this is, as you can see is returning a 400 error, but I don't know how to get the full response from the server when using async await in axios, it shows it easily when using then and catch but I can only get this simple response.

When printing the body / headers in the console everything seems fine, it's the same request I did before but it fails here for some reason...

```
Making :3 Accounts
ERROR Create acc:Error: Request failed with status code 400
ERROR unautinit:Error: Request failed with status code 400
ERROR provision:Error: Request failed with status code 400
ERROR Salesforce:Error: Request failed with status code 400
ERROR Create acc:Error: Request failed with status code 400
ERROR unautinit:Error: Request failed with status code 400
ERROR provision:Error: Request failed with status code 400
ERROR Salesforce:Error: Request failed with status code 400
ERROR Create acc:Error: Request failed with status code 400
ERROR unautinit:Error: Request failed with status code 400
ERROR provision:Error: Request failed with status code 400
ERROR Salesforce:Error: Request failed with status code 400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I was able to use to resolve this is:

1. Using For..in loop that is placed within an async function
2. Using this way of requesting: const provisionResult = await axios(provision)

Answer (score 1):

With async/await this is relatively simple:

```
for(...) {
   const result = await axios(...); // wait for the request to finish
   // do something with your result
}
```

Comment: But that has to be placed inside a function if I use await in a loop it says that it must be inside an async function - how do i solve that?

Comment: Yeah, you need to put it inside an async function. You should really read up on async/await if you want to do async code in JS. On StackOverflow we try to solve problems others have and teach the person a little. But not give extensive lessons on already well documented things like async/await. @makat

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to have your function return the Promise that axios is creating. It's a little hard to tell with the spacing of your sample, but it looks like just adding a `return` to this line will work:

```
return axios(createAcc)
```

Then, instead of using a `setTimeout` and loop, you need to make the first call, wait for it to finish, then in the `then()` method, make the next call if you have one:

```
var merchantsToCreate = getFromSomewhere();
var currentIndex = 0;

function makeNextAccount() {
  if (currentIndex < merchantsToCreate.length - 1) {
    currentIndex++;
    accountCreationFlow(merchantsToCreate[i], emails[i])
      .then(makeNextAccount); // <- will make the next account
  }
}

makeNextAccount(); // kick off the "loop"
```

Comment: I tried doing that with await but it seems to be failing for some reason

Comment: If you could update your answer with what you tried, maybe we could help. It is an appropriate technique, so it might just be some typo or something.

Comment: OKAY - got it all fixed - used a for..in loop and it seems to work, I have no idea why it failed before , I deleted some logging, maybe i broke something and didn't notice